# How to use lsof with SSH ControlPath?

Tags: ssh, sockets, lsof

I am extensively using SSH ControlPath and would like to use the `lsof` tool in order to check which process is keeping a ControlPath socket up and running.
I am using `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016` which comes with Ubuntu 16.04.
My SSH options (in ~/.ssh/config) are like this:

```
Host *
...
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath /tmp/sshcontrol-%C
  ControlPersist yes
...
```

And this is what I get when I do first connection to a host:

```
srw------- 1 enzo enzo  0 2016-06-15 11:35:15 sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac
```

But if i try to get details about the process using that socket with `lsof` I get these "*strange*" results.

```
    $ lsof /tmp/sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac
    lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
          Output information may be incomplete.
    $ sudo lsof /tmp/sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac
    $ lsof | grep sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac
    lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
          Output information may be incomplete.
    ssh       2044            enzo    4u     unix 0x0000000000000000       0t0      42942 /tmp/sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac.tBKTDPNcaBZjlV2T type=STREAM
    ssh       2044            enzo    5u     unix 0x0000000000000000       0t0      55186 /tmp/sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac.tBKTDPNcaBZjlV2T type=STREAM
    $ lsof /tmp/sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac.tBKTDPNcaBZjlV2T
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: status error on /tmp/sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac.tBKTDPNcaBZjlV2T: No such file or directory
lsof 4.89
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhKlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-E] [+|-e s] [+|-f[gG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
```

That is, the "*actual*" file name associated to that socket is not what "*it should be*": lsof reports an extra filename extension.
The other tool for sockets `ss` gives similar results.

One final weird behavior. I see I have a socket in `/tmp` to be used by `kdewallet`. It's called (in my case) `kwallet5_enzo.socket`.
If I use `lsof` over it, this is what I get:

```
$ lsof /tmp/kwallet5_enzo.socket
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
kwalletd5  1689 enzo    2u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   27355 /tmp/kwallet5_enzo.socket type=STREAM
startkde   1690 enzo   19u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   27802 /tmp/kwallet5_enzo.socket type=STREAM
dbus-laun  1742 enzo   19u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   27802 /tmp/kwallet5_enzo.socket type=STREAM
dbus-daem  1743 enzo   19u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   27802 /tmp/kwallet5_enzo.socket type=STREAM
start_kde  1800 enzo   19u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   27802 /tmp/kwallet5_enzo.socket type=STREAM
kwrapper5  1843 enzo   19u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0   27802 /tmp/kwallet5_enzo.socket type=STREAM
ssh        3023 enzo    5u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0  104592 /tmp/sshcontrol-e10fedd3d8237e382300367ff49267fa193957ac.sGsWVH3Aqg03Hc7D type=STREAM
ssh        8862 enzo    5u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 1131569 /tmp/sshcontrol-485e2aeac2a50cd6880fd929681d0e3a55817f06.deg4pBWKy2nusvrK type=STREAM
ssh       31767 enzo    5u  unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0 1006327 /tmp/sshcontrol-f1b458a85cd2aa9d5c115abc12afee9f485ad6b0.g2QSMGUDOG1LY8bZ
```

I (correctly) see a number of processes accessing that socket. But I also see three unwanted sockets related to the `ControlPath` feature by SSH!
I start thinking more about bugs and less about my own ignorance.

How can I reliably check which process is using that socket file?

Comment: Maybe you need http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair

Comment: I did used lsof and ss. But they seemed not to work. And I don't know the pid of the process, but I do know the name of the socket, which appears to be wrong despite both SSH configuration and ls command show otherwise!